# The Test class require the method from a concrete class to be static

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, interface, junit4

The test class requires a method to be defined as static in the concrete class. But the concrete class implements a method from an interface.

The interface does not allow the implemented method to be static.

**Interface:**

```
public interface ArithmeticSkeleton {

    public int operation(int a, int b);

}
```

**Concrete Class**

```
public class Divide implements ArithmeticSkeleton{

    public int operation(int a, int b) {        
        return (a / b);
    }
}
```

**jUnit test case:**

```
public class ArithmeticSkeletontest {

    private ArithmeticSkeleton as;

    @Test
    public void testDivision() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("5", Divide.operation(10, 2));
    }

}
```

However, the Test code does not allow Divide.operation to be accessed.

Comment: You cannot access the operation method in such way, you must use static approach if you want to do so, otherwise just new Divide().operation(10, 2) is enough

Comment: As well as using the answers here, you'll need to change `"5"` to `5` inside `assertEquals` to make this test pass.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize object of class Divide to access its methods:

```
   public void testDivision() throws Exception {
            Divide divide = new Divide();
            assertEquals(5, divide.operation(10, 2));
// you need to change "5" to 5 to pass this test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation method is not static. Therefor you must instantiate an object of the Divide class like this in your test

```
@Test
public void testDivision() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("5", new Divide().operation(10, 2));
}
```